# Strange Accordion component behaviour in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, accordion

I've an `Accordion` component in my Flex application and works great, but I found a little glitch in its behaviour.

While one of its menus is opening, it shows a white rectangle and, when it completely loads, it shows me the content. **But I want to show the whole content without this "white" rectangle when it loads.**

For example:

**Image 1**: My Accordion is ready to use

[image: Accordion ready]

**Image 2**: I want to open another submenu, so while it's opening, a white rectangle is shown (I was really quickly to take an screenshot)

[image: White rectangle]

**Image 3**: Recently opened submenu is fully loaded

[image: Submenu loaded]

It's really hard to explain in a few words, but I think that someone understood me. Can you help me? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is my source code:

```
<mx:Accordion id="accordion" width="100%" height="90%" verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0" creationPolicy="all">
    <mx:Form id="menu1" label="Vehículos" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Grid>
            <mx:GridRow>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/cars/car1.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/cars/car2.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
            </mx:GridRow>
            <mx:GridRow>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/cars/car3.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/cars/car4.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
            </mx:GridRow>
        </mx:Grid>
    </mx:Form>
    <mx:Form id="menu2" label="Señales" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Grid >
            <mx:GridRow>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/signals/X01A20.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/signals/X01A21.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
            </mx:GridRow>
            <mx:GridRow>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/signals/X01B10.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/signals/X02A01.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
            </mx:GridRow>
            <mx:GridRow>
                <mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:Image source="./assets/signals/X01A01.png"/>
                </mx:GridItem>
            </mx:GridRow>
        </mx:Grid>
    </mx:Form>
</mx:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is caused by an optimization within flex.

Check out the [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_05.html) on this topic

The white screen is shown due to the fact that the component your are trying to display in the other tabs is in the process of being rendered, and this rendering takes a bit too long.
That is why you experience this hiccup.

Though it is not advisable to set the `creationPolicy` to `all`, this would probably solve your problem.

Keep in mind that you should actually never set the creationPolicy to all, but look for other solutions like preloading your assets, object pooling, ..

**EDIT**

Why are your grid components in an extra form container?
 
I believe this is the reason why setting creationPolicy to all doesn't work for your your example.

One way of improving performance would be to minimize nesting levels, effectively try to remove your extra obsolete form containers.

Second, when using , the positioning of your items will be automatically calculated every time, which takes a bit longer to render. Absolute positioning of your elements will most likely be a furhter optimization.

Third, try loading your png images into your application in some sort of cache at runtime by using some sort of asset loading strategy.
Your objects will then be stored in memory and should be way faster to access.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, but how can I preload my assets? Which events should I study? Can you edit your post to explain me, please? Thanks so much :)

Comment: Anyways, I try to set `creationPolicy="all"` in my `Accordion` component, but it didn't work.

Comment: What kind of component are you adding to your tabs? could you show some more code?

Comment: I updated my own question to add some source code. The first "form" loads fine, but the second one shows me "the white rectangle". Thanks :)